# integrate $\int e^{-iwt}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integral:

$$ \int e^{-iwt}dt$$

I know that $\int e^{kx}=\frac{e^{kx}}{k}$ so therefore the $ \int e^{-iwt}dt$ would be $\frac{e^{-iwt}}{-iw}$ but Wolfram Alpha says that it is $\int \frac{ie^{-iwt}}{w}$. Why is my assumption wrong? Or is it in fact the same answer?

Comment: Did you mean ' the $\int e^{−iwt}dt$ would be $\frac{e^{−iwt}}{−iw}$' ?

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $i$ and remember that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Yes @Hippalectryon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about "rationalising" your answer to write it in it's simplest form. For example, in Mathematics, we prefer writing $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. It's essentially the same thing, but it's much more elegant to divide by an integer, than to divide by a surd - it's much "softer" on the eye and easier to work with, in the case where no calculators are available.

In this case, instead of a surd, you have $i$ in your denominator, which you want to get rid of, for the same reasons as stated above.

To do this, keep in mind $i^2 =-1$.

Now, multiplying through by $\frac{i}{i}$, gives:

$\frac{e^{-iwt}}{-iw} \times \frac{i}{i} = \frac{ie^{-iwt}}{w}$, the desired result.

So essentially:
Your answer is correct, but not written in it's simplest form.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{e^{-iwt}}{-iw}=\frac{ie^{-iwt}}{-i^2w}=\frac{ie^{-iwt}}{w}$$

Answer (score 2):

$i^2=-1$ hence $\frac{e^{-iwt}}{-iw}\cdot\frac{i}i=\frac{i\cdot e^{-iwt}}{w}$